# Why I got an error saying that no one exception is thrown?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, netbeans, executor

I have this in a class that implements Callable :

```
public class MasterCrawler implements Callable {
    public Object call() throws SQLException {
        resumeCrawling();
        return true;
    }
    //more code with methods that throws an SQLException
}
```

In other class that execute this Callable, something like this:

```
MasterCrawler crawler = new MasterCrawler();
try{
    executorService.submit(crawler); //crawler is the class that implements Callable
}(catch SQLException){
    //do something here
}
```

But I got an error and a message of the IDE that an SQLException is never throw. This is because I'm executing in a ExecutorService?

**UPDATE**: So the submit don't throws an SQLException. How I can do to execute the Callable (run as thread) and catch the exception?

**SOLVED:**

```
public class MasterCrawler implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        try {
            resumeCrawling();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            return sqle;            
        }
     }
}


Future resC = es.submit(masterCrawler);
if (resC.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) instanceof SQLException) {
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: The Callable throws an Exception. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `submit`, you are passing an object. You are not calling `call()`.

**EDIT**

`Submit` returns a [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) f. When you call `f.get()`, the method can throw an [ExecutionException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) if a problem is encountered during the execution of the callable. If so, it will contain the exception thrown by `call()`.

By submitting your Callable to the executor, you are actually asking it to execute it (asynchronously). No need for further action. Just retrieve the future and wait.

**ABOUT THE SOLUTION**

Although your solution will work, this not very clean code, because you are hijacking the return value of Call. Try something like this:

```
public class MasterCrawler implements Callable<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void call() throws SQLException {
        resumeCrawling();
        return null;
    }

    public void resumeCrawling() throws SQLException {
        // ... if there is a problem
        throw new SQLException();
    }    

}

public void doIt() {

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<Void> resC = es.submit(new MasterCrawler());

    try {

        resC.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Success

    } catch ( ExecutionException ex ) {

        SQLException se = (SQLException) ex.getCause();
        // Do something with the exception

    } catch ( TimeoutException ex ) {

        // Execution timed-out

    } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {

        // Execution was interrupted

    } 

}
```

Comment: How I do to get the Exception thrown by the call method?

Comment: @ditkin No, this is not the right way to do it, because if you want to notify the caller/invoker, catching the exception inside the call won't tell you how to pass it to the caller/invoker. You need to let Future catch it.

Comment: I'm cathing the exception inside the call method and returning it and doind a threatement with an IF. Looks a little strange, I will find another way, but for now, solver my problem.

Comment: @Renato Dinhani Conceição I have updated my answer to provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The submit method does not throw a SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

It's because SQLException never will be throw by the crawler.

Try use `finally` instead of `catch` and see if you will have a problem or it works.

Comment: No, this won't help at all... And, you cannot use finally without a catch in the first place.

Comment: Wait... I can yes, I do it constantly. You can do this if you don't want catch exceptions on this step of code, but in a more global scope.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? When I try your code, Eclipse complains "unhandled exception type Exception". This makes sense because the `Callable` interface defines the `call()` method to throw `Exception`. Just because your implementation class declares a more restricted exception type, the calling program cannot count on that. It expects you to catch Exception.